# Scrolling X not possible on iOS

Tags: ios, css, ionic-framework

When i load the screen on iOS scrolling in the X axis is not possible on iOS. No issues on android. When clicking a button which refreshes the data on the screen scrolling is possible again.

Anybody an idea what could cause this?

```
<div class="container">
    <!--  CONTENT -->
    <div class="scroll-container">
        <!-- CONTENT-->
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    overflow-x: scroll;
  }
  .scroll-container {
    min-width: 100%;
    overflow: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
   -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

According to **[the docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/scroll/Scroll/#scroll)** you can add a scrolling section in your content using `ion-scroll`:

> `ion-scroll`
>
> Scroll is a non-flexboxed scroll area that can scroll horizontally or
>   vertically. `ion-scroll` Can be used in places where you may not need a
>   full page scroller, but a highly customized one, such as image scubber
>   or comment scroller.

```
<ion-scroll scrollX="true" scrollY="true">
    <!-- ... --> 
</ion-scroll>
```

Demo source:

```
<ion-header>

  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Scroll</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>


<ion-content>

  <ion-scroll scrollX="true" scrollY="true" style="width: 100%; height: 100%">
    <div class="map-div"></div>
  </ion-scroll>

</ion-content>


<style>
  .map-div {
    width: 2600px;
    height: 1400px;
    background: url('./assets/map.jpeg') no-repeat;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: It's really strange, sometimes scrolling works and sometimes not, even with a ion-Scroll

Comment: Are you getting the data that is shown there async? If yes, what happens if you get the instance of the content via `@ViewChild(Content) content: Content;` and then you call `this.content.resize()` after getting that data?

Comment: Yes, i'm getting the data async, Also what i noticed is, that when i update a css value in the inspector scrolling is possible again. For example the `display: inline-block;` value. Content resize had no effect.

Comment: Is there a github repo that I could access to so I can inspect what could be going on?

Comment: I create some gists for you, please wait a second.

Comment: In the Ionic demo, they add `style="width: 100%; height: 100%"` inline in the `ion-scroll` element. What happens if you try that and also remove all the css rules that may be affecting the `ion-scroll`? (for example, [these two rules](https://gyazo.com/a2058d874f52d80755a4199102fd1011))

Comment: Thank you, when i remove and add this, Ion-scroll has a height of zero.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178800/discussion-between-sebaferreras-and-olivier).